# How can I create in Tableau stacked column chart for three variables and discrete OX data?

Tags: excel, charts, tableau-api, stacked-chart

I am trying to create a stacked column chart in Tableau. But something is wrong and I just can't do it. There are some examples of my tries:

[image]

However, I can easily do it in excel:
[image]

That is a Link to the data: 
[Data for the Chart](https://www.dropbox.com/s/v3helqx0botws37/PythonExport%20-%20Copy.xlsx?dl=0)

for creating on the OX axis year and week I converted them to the string format and them concatenated them.

How can I create in Tableau stacked column chart for three variables and discrete OX data?

Comment: Does tableau do overlays of some sort - since you already have it in excel copy/ paste...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reshape your data so it looks like this:

[image]

You can use the [Tableau Excel Add-on](https://community.tableau.com/docs/DOC-10394) to reshape it or do it in Python given your data file name.

This way the New, Closed, Open are all in a single column and your Quantity can be summed in a single column (I renamed those columns to Type and Quantity)

Then you can create your desired result.

[image]

Comment: Reshaping the data is a good solution, but there is another alternative as well, using Tableau’s Measure Names and Measure Values features to treat several measures similarly. Read about that in the online help. It would have let you get the chart you wanted without reshaping the data in this case - and is a useful feature to understand in many cases.

Comment: I don;t think that method would allow for distinct coloring of the bars sections.

Comment: Sure it does, Put Measure Values on the Row Shelf, Measure Names on Color, Put whatever Measures you want on the Measure Values shelf, Choose bar as your mark type